# Angular 2 Browser and OS *crash* (Windows and Debian 8)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, angular, debian

I was working with angular forms when I came across a small problem, when i added the following select my chrome stopped working and I couldn't use my OS until I pressed ctrl + alt + del.

```
<select #input="ngModel" name="input" ngModel id="input" [disabled]="input.valid" required [(ngModel)]="input">
  <option value="Option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

This bug works on windows 7 and debian and i tested it in chrome, IE (Windows only) and firefox.

if you want to try, go to: http://plnkr.co/edit/LOHt4ZoHYjs2agFisvZR?p=info

Is there anyone that can explain this to me.

Comment: Why would you do this ? This is absolutely nonsense.

Comment: I know but its a problem that might be kind of serious.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing like this just do :
suppose your form name is "myForm"

```
<select [(ngModel)]="input" name="input" id="input" [disabled]="myForm.input.valid" required >
  <option value="Option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option_2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option_3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

In your ts file just declare the `input:any;`
I think it will solve your problem

Comment: can you share your code in form of plunker ..then i will give you better answer

Comment: Nope I cant, when i type the closing " plunker crashes instantly, but i can send it to you without the closing tag so you can experience it your self.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LOHt4ZoHYjs2agFisvZR?p=info, in hero-form.component.html there is a div, remove it and run it. In plucker only the tab crashes, not the browser and os.